# How to Immediately execute paintevent

Tags: c#

hallo everybody everywhere

I do have this small piece of code

```
if (Bitmap != null) {
    pnlBitmap.Invalidate();
    this.Update();

    ProcessTheBitMap();

    if (! BitmapAdded) {
        Bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

it should always display the bitmap before processing.
paintevent however is startet after completion of code and by that time the   bitmap could be disposed.
So how can I solve this problem ?
for your answers thanks in advance

Comment: By *not* blocking the UI thread. Paint events are sent by the OS and processed by the UI thread. If you run `ProcessTheBitMap()` on the UI thread, it's busy and can't handle any repaint events. Whatever `ProcessTheBitMap()` does, it should happen in the background, eg by using `Task.Run(()=>ProcessTheBitMap());`. You'll have to explain what you are doing to get a specific answer

Comment: You could use Refresh instead of Invalidate; not recommended usually but here it should just what yopu want.

Comment: @TaW - that would _not_ show the picture before processing...